# Retaining variable value in a dataframe in r

Tags: r, retain

I have a `dataframe` in R

```
ID subgroup First.ID Var
103  17     TRUE     abc
103  17     FALSE    xyz
103  17     FALSE    def
103  17     FALSE    pqr
106  16     TRUE     abc
106  16     FALSE    pqr
```

First.ID is created to identify first element in the group(ID). 
I want to create a new variable that should retain its value in a by group. Here, the by group i will use is ID variable.
My new `dataframe` should look like this

```
ID subgroup First.ID Var Condition
103  17     TRUE     abc abc
103  17     FALSE    xyz abc or xyz
103  17     FALSE    def abc or xyz or def
103  17     FALSE    pqr abc or xyz or def or pqr
106  16     TRUE     abc abc
106  16     FALSE    pqr abc or pqr
```

Comment: That output doesn't look useful at all. What's the purpose of creating it?

Comment: The variable Var actually has conditions like (product_number=1 and product_group="A"). Every instance has a condition. I want to summarize the conditions separated by " or ". The last condition will then be used.

Answer (score 3):

```
DF <- read.table(text="ID subgroup First.ID Var
103  17     TRUE     abc
103  17     FALSE    xyz
103  17     FALSE    def
103  17     FALSE    pqr
106  16     TRUE     abc
106  16     FALSE    pqr", header=TRUE)

library(plyr)
cumpaste <- function(x, sep) {
  sapply(seq_along(x), function(y,z,sep) paste(z[1:y], 
          collapse=sep), z=x, sep=sep)
}

ddply(DF, .(ID), transform, condition=cumpaste(Var, " or "))

#    ID subgroup First.ID Var                condition
# 1 103       17     TRUE abc                      abc
# 2 103       17    FALSE xyz               abc or xyz
# 3 103       17    FALSE def        abc or xyz or def
# 4 103       17    FALSE pqr abc or xyz or def or pqr
# 5 106       16     TRUE abc                      abc
# 6 106       16    FALSE pqr               abc or pqr
```

Comment: I am a newbie to R language. Can you make me understand what would be the value of "y" in paste function. As we are only passing "x" and "sep" when cumpaste function is called.

Comment: The values of `y` are the values of `seq_along(x)` passed to the function in a loop.